# Java Swing renders a different background

Tags: java, swing, graphics, awt, rendering

I'm working on a game. The issue I'm having is that before the game rendering starts (should render a black background) it shows a white background. It happens for a second and then starts the correct rendering. I'm not sure how to fix this issue.

All the rendering code is running inside a Thread. I tried to make the window visible after the first rendering but I got an NPE on the createImage method.

[image]

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Window extends JFrame implements Runnable {
    private Thread windowThread;
    private int width, height;
    private String windowName;
    private boolean isExecuting;
    private GameState gameState;

    private Graphics graphics;

    public Window() {
        loadWindowConfiguration();
        windowThread = new Thread(this);
    }

    private void loadWindowConfiguration() {
        setWindowProperties();
    }

    private void setWindowProperties() {
        this.windowName = Constants.WINDOW_NAME;
        this.width = Constants.WINDOW_WIDTH;
        this.height = Constants.WINDOW_HEIGHT;
        this.setTitle(windowName);
        this.setSize(new Dimension(this.width, this.height));
        this.setResizable(Constants.IS_RESIZABLE_WINDOW);
        this.setFocusable(Constants.IS_FOCUSABLE_WINDOW);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setVisible(Constants.IS_VISIBLE_WINDOW); // Set to true
        graphics = (Graphics2D)this.getGraphics();
    }

    public void update(double delta) {
        gameState.update(delta);
    }

    public void render() {
        Image img = this.createImage(this.getWindowWidth(), this.getWindowHeight());
        Graphics g = img.getGraphics();
        Graphics2D doubleBuffer = (Graphics2D) g;

        doubleBuffer.setColor(getBackground());
        //doubleBuffer.fillRect(0, 0, this.getWindowWidth(), this.getWindowHeight());

        gameState.render(doubleBuffer);

        graphics.drawImage(img, 0, 0, this);
    }

    public void startWindow() { windowThread.start(); }

    public void stopWindow() {
        this.isExecuting = false;
    }

    private void clean() {
        graphics.dispose();
        this.dispose();
        windowThread.interrupt();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        this.isExecuting = true;

        gameState.loadGame();

        while(this.isExecuting) {
            update(delta);
            render();

        }

        clean();
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) Don't use getGraphics() to do painting. 2) Don't use a Thread with a while loop. For animation use a Swing Timer. 3) No need for the BufferedImage, just do the custom painting on a JPanel. 4) The just use the `setBackground(...)` method of the panel Read the [Swing Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html). The section on `Custom Painting` and `How to Use Swing Timer` should be a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `setBackground()` method from Java AWT in order to create a background.

Are you using Eclipse to build your application? If so, just use WindowBuilder and everything should be on the side toolbar if you are having problems rendering a background.

As WJS suggested, I recommend you read the documentation for Java Swing. Most of your concerns should be able to be answered at this [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/package-summary.html).